# iPhone Video compression on/off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video-capture

I have implemented video capturing by:

```
IImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];    
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
if ([sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie ]){
    imagePicker.mediaTypes =  sourceTypes;
}           
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
```

I can record video and send it to YouTube using YouTube API, but if the video length is more then about 5 minutes, and I click USE - the application is closed. But no problem appear if I select even 10 minutes video from library (i see "Compressing video" progress), video is saved to my view and uploaded to YouTube.

Can anybody tell me what the problem could be?

Comment: What are you clicking “Use” on?

Comment: I click USE button in the bottom right corner of the UIImagePickerController. It is a standard button. At the bottom left corner i get RETAKE button.

Comment: OK, maybe I can change question a little. When I record video using UIImagePickerController and send it somewhere it is about 4MB, and if I select THE SAME video from library it is about 1MB. How to make file smaller right after recording?

Answer (score 1):

You used QualityTypeHigh with high resolution 1280x720. so it take so much memory.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

[imagePicker setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityQualityTypeMedium];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

[imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:30];

imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

[imagePicker release];
```